# List data sources from multiple .mxds contained in one folder using Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, mxd

I have a folder containing multiple .mxd files. I wish to list all of the layer names and data sources for each .mxd from the folder. I am using the following code which lists the above for one .mxd but how do I loop the code to work through all .mxds in the folder?

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("D:\MXDs\Air_quality.mxd")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
        print " MIS Name: " + lyr.name + "  Data Source: " + lyr.dataSource
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import arcpy,os
>>> dp=r'D:\MXDs'
>>> arcpy.env.workspace=r'D:\MXDs'
>>> mxds=arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")
>>> for mxd in mxds:
...     fp=os.path.join(dp,str(mxd))
...     md=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fp)
...     layerlist=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(md)
...     for layer in layerlist:
...         if layer.supports("DATASOURCE"):
...             print "layer name :"+layer.name+"source :"+layer.dataSource
```