# RuntimeError: Object: CreateObject cannot open map document

Tags: arcpy, mxd, feature-service

I need to get a list of all the layers in all of the .mxd files located in a certain directory as these layers have been published to AGOL through the the agency of the mapping documents and I now want to use a different method for updating AGOL feature services. Problem is it will take much long time to open each mxd and write down each layer. I find this script on GIS SE and I adapt to my parms:

```
import arcpy, os

dp = r"C:\DBAGROUP\ArcGIS\AGOL\MXD"
arcpy.env.workspace = dp
mxds=arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")
for mxd in mxds:
    fp=os.path.join(dp, str(mxd))
    md=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fp)
    layerlist=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(md)
    for layer in layerlist:
        if layer.supports("DATASOURCE"):
            print "layer name :"+layer.name+"source :"+layer.dataSource
```

Here is original post:
[List data sources from multiple .mxds contained in one folder using Arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318342/list-data-sources-from-multiple-mxds-contained-in-one-folder-using-arcpy)

Only problem is I get error when trying to open map document:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 3, in <module>
    md=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fp)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.7\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 652, in __init__
    super(MapDocumentMethods, self).__init__(mxd)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.7\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\_base.py", line 47, in __init__
    for arg in args))
RuntimeError: Object: CreateObject cannot open map document
```

I am running as admin so permission should not be issue but what is?

Comment: Have you reviewed these earlier Q&As with the same error message? https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=RuntimeError%3A+Object%3A+CreateObject+cannot+open+map+document+is%3Aquestion

Comment: What version of ArcMap are you running ArcPy with?  Are any of the MXDs you are trying to create MapDocument objects last saved using a version later than your ArcMap version can work with?

Comment: @ PolyGeo that could be the case as we are moving towards ArcPro (hence we are grabbing all of the service layers created with ArcMap so they can be used in Pro now.) I would have thought though that ArcPy would bomb somewhere before if it were a version issue.

Comment: Is the error coming on the first, every or only some MXDs?

Comment: It must be the first because not one print statement is able to execute. Checked version of arcmap and map docs and all are 10.7.1

Comment: @PolyGeo turns out it was the path. The post gives a sample path as I can't reveal my network directories but they use \\at the beginning of the server path. When using it as a raw text string variable Python converts it to \\\\ and therefore the object could open mxd because they didn't exist at \\\\path to mxds. Changed from r"\\path\mxds" to "//path/mxds". Worked fine after that.

Comment: Excellent.  Hope you have time to write that up as a self-answer.